# Opening a handle to a drive in Windows permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, driver

I'm opening a drive directly via CreateFile to get a handle so I can send scsi commands via IOCtl to custom hardware (which presents as a mass storage device) from a windows service.

The problem is that in order to do this my service needs to run as an administrator (or I get access denied errors). In practice this won't be problem under most circumstances (usually we run as Local System) but under some circumstances we run as a domain account so is there a permission I can give to a domain user account to allow access that is a little finer grained than local administrator to get this working?

[Device Driver access permissions for domain users in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249151/device-driver-access-permissions-for-domain-users-in-windows-7) and [SPTI/SCSI operations from a Windows 7 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328106/spti-scsi-operations-from-a-windows-7-application) are variants of the same question but don't give that finer grained answer.

Comment: Any such permission would be equivalent to admin access, so there'd be little point.  It might be possible to change the access control rules on the specific device, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Consider isolating the code that needs to write directly to the device from the code that sometimes needs domain access, i.e., implement it as two separate services, one of which always runs as local system.

Comment: I can see the point you're making but sometimes it's easier to ask for a specific permission from a sysadmin rather than a blanket I need local admin rights sort of thing. Just found myself wondering if anyone had found a "lesser" permission.

Comment: @Peterl: it's worth asking, somebody else might know something useful.  But it seems likely that there is no such solution.  If the problem is political rather than technical, you could consider putting the logic you need into a (user mode?) device driver.  That way, there's no way for the sysadmin to reduce its privileges. :-)